# What are the different types of flours used in cooking Idly, Dosa, Halwa, Ladoo and Upma?

Tags: rice, flour, indian-cuisine

What are the different types of flours used in making Rava Idly, Dosa, Halwa, Ladoo and Upma in Indian Cuisine?

What are the differences between Wheat flour, Semolina flour and Rice flour in cooking these dishes?

Comment: Why is down-vote in this question? :O

Comment: @Mistu4u guess this question seems vague to answer buddy

Answer (score 2):

basically in indian dishes whatever you mentioned above were using these flours as common interigents

- wheat flour
- rice flour
- aata
- corn flour
- semolina flour

basically the diffrence is their tendency to absorb water and the time which they take for cook ,for e.g cooking parathas with wheat flour will take more time than aata,

Hope it clarifies the basic things,for better clarification use brednan's video

Answer (score 1):

This may help you make some decisions about what flours to use/keep on hand.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WXGjKr25_Gk

But in general, the difference between flours relates mostly to whether your looking for elasticity (gluten content) vs crispness (rice flour). For semolina, there is obviously very different ways to cook it such as in puddings or creamy dishes but it can also be dusted on things as a breading to make it crunchy.